# Найти первый подсписок по букве. Python

Tags: python

Всем привет!
Мне нужно найти первый подсписок в слове по какой-то букве. Например, пользователь дает слово, затем дает букву, и если в слове есть эта буква, нам нужно проверить, есть ли у нас 2 следующие буквы? если да, то печатаем букву + 2 следующие буквы в слове. Если буквы нет в слове, ничего не печатайеm.
Например:

word: banan

letter: n

"nan"

word: Orange

letter: r

"ran"

word: python

letter: n

мой код совершенно неправильный. не понимаю, как это сделать.

```
word=input("word: ")
letter=input("letter: ")
lst=[i[-2:] for line in word for i in line.split()]

print(lst)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в данном случае не обязательно использовать цикл:

```
word = 'banan'
letter = 'b'

i = word.find(letter)
print(word[i:i+3])  # ban
```

**UPD**

как верно заметил в комментариях ganz, необходимо немного изменить параметры вызова функции:

```
word = 'python'
letter = 'o'

i = word.find(letter,0,-2)
print(word[i:i+3])
```

Comment: word='bananas'
>>> letter = 'b'
>>>
>>> i = word.find(letter)
>>> print(word[i:i+3])
ban
>>> letter = 's'
>>> i = word.find(letter)
>>> print(word[i:i+3])
s Хотя по условию не должно быть вывода

Comment: согласен, упустил условие.

Comment: i = word.find(letter,0,-2) решит проблему, как я и пытался написать выше, но затупил D

Comment: всем огромное спасибо !!!!

Answer (score 1):

для этого проще воспользоваться функцией str.find(chr,start,stop) то есть str(chr,0,-2)
либо

```
for chr in enumerate(string)-2:
  if string[chr]==search_char:
        print(string[chr:chr+2])
        break #так как нет смысла продолжать ибо есть результат
```